# Which big fat web sites use servlet technology (Again)?

Tags: php, servlets

I had a lot of internal discussion about PHP vs. Servlets with all the common arguments about scripting vs. 'true' languages etc., which all seem rather weak to me when it comes to the real world. Now decisions are to be made and I'd like to have one based on success stories. For PHP/scripting there are a lot of great testimonials like amazon, facebook and others, but I can't find real great sites that are driven by JSP/Servlets. Are there any?

... and please, all you closers:

> but if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers (YEP)
> - matters that are unique to the programming profession (YEP)
>
> … then you're in the right place to ask your question!

(from faq, 2 of 4 isn't that bad, I think)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not completeley aware of the international situation, but at least in Germany Java seems to be commonly used for online banking sites. I know of at least 4 big german banks that use java for their online banking applications.
Also, logistics providers like UPS or DHL rely on JSP or Servlets for their sites.

My general impression is, that java-powered websites are especially popular among big "real-world-companies" while scripting languages like PHP are widely used by pure internet comanies.

Comment: +1 for discriminating between different types of organisations. This is probably because they have more system integration and code auditing to do. FWIW the Co-Operative bank (UK) online banking  uses Java

Comment: I think HSBC does as well. At least in the UK

Answer (score 2):

[Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) uses Java. According to [this article](http://royal.pingdom.com/2007/02/26/what-the-webs-most-popular-sites-are-running-on/), TechCrunch and FeedBurner both use Java servlets. You may want to look over this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294064/most-popular-j2ee-based-websites) too for a lot of sites using J2EE.